# How is the performance of a model affected by adding a ReLU to fully connected layers?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-neural-networks, activation-functions, performance, relu

How significant is adding a ReLU to fully connected (FC) layers? Is it necessary, or how is the performance of a model affected by adding ReLU to FC layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReLU is [piecewise linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function) that outputs the received input directly if it's positive, or outputs a zero. i.e., $max(0, x)$

[image: img alt]

#### How significant is adding relu to full connected layers?

ReLU, being an [activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function), will determine what the output of the nodes in your FCs are. Since it's a non-linear function, one significance is it will allow the nodes in your model to learn  complex mappings between the inputs and the outputs. Compared to using a linear function, it will allow back-propagation since it has a derivative, allowing the neural network to have the advantage of stacking of multiple FC layers.

#### Is it necessary?

ReLU (and non-linear activation functions in general) will introduce non-linear properties in a neural network that enables it to learn more complex arbitrary structures in the inputs. Without activation functions **between the layers**, your neural network will simply be a linear function, regardless of the number of layers it has. Why? A linear function + linear function gives a linear function. Additionally, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9783865).

#### How is the performance affected by adding ReLU?

Compared to no activation function at all, it will be slower to train but [will only behave like a linear regression model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/253394/296297). So ReLU will increase the power of the model by making it non-linear.
However, compared to other non-linear activation functions like tanH, ReLU will speed up training as (1) its computation step is cheaper i.e., $0.0$ or $x$ without additional operations (2) its gradient just depends on the sign of the input $x$. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226923/why-do-we-use-relu-in-neural-networks-and-how-do-we-use-it)